# Event handling in React Native without lambda expression?

Tags: lambda, ecmascript-6, react-native

This style is what I see on tutorials everywhere

```
  onChangeText = { (e)=>{this.setState({input:e})} }
```

Another style without lambda expressions

```
  changeText: function(text) {
    this.setState({input: text});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <React.TextInput onChangeText={ this.changeText } />
    );
  }
```

However this doesn't.

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <React.TextInput onChangeText = { function(text) {this.setState({input: text});} }/>
    );
  }
```

1. For code block 2, where does this.changeText get the input text from?
2. For code block 3, why can't I declare the function inline?

I'm not sure what's the proper terms to look this up, so I appreciate if anybody can point me in the direction

Comment: The correct term in Javascript is an *arrow function*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between ES6 arrow functions and classical functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
text => { /* `this` is capture from the enclosing context */ }
```

vs

```
function (text) { /* `this` is set by the caller */ }
```

in your third code block, I have no idea what `this` will be, but there is **absolutely no way** it can be your instance class (because the caller of `onChangeText` prop don't know you) - so `this.setState` can't work.

However this should work:

```
<React.TextInput onChangeText = {
  (function(text) {this.setState({input: text})}).bind(this)
} />
```

but it's not as efficient as using ES6 arrow function (and not very concise).

---

Also you must know that the code block 2 only works if using React.createClass(), because all methods are **magically** auto-bounded to the class instance.
If using ES6 Class, you must do something like:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  changeText = text => {
    this.setState({ ... });
  };
  render () { ... }
}
```

(using class property will bind to this)